# TCPDF and Javascript

Tags: javascript, tcpdf

I've have a pdf generated with TCPDF+XHTML. Now I need to use some javascript also. There are some javascript examples at tcpdf-site, but they aren't relevant for this, but from those examples I've noticed that the javascript has a bit different syntax than I'm used to.

Basically what I want is to have textfield, and if you type something in it, the text appears at other places too. But I have no idea how to get events to work with this textfield.

I do the xhtml output whit $pdf->writeHTML(...) and JS output with $pdf->IncludeJS($js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO Javascript in PDFs is terribly inconsistent. Recommend you avoid it unless it's really, really, really necessary.